# Tensorflow tf.get_variable() by index

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, data-science

Good afternoon.
I continue to study tensorflow, and now stuck on a problem with reusing variable "W"
Here's the code snippet:http://pastebin.com/VZETt2ud

I want to avoid hardcode and get values from restored model (instead of 10 - get_value(), etc).
I have read several threads here, but everywhere only the whole varible was needed. However, I don't understand how to fetch properly, for instance, number 784 from here:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name = "W")
```

I tried this:

```
idx = tf.constant([0])
temp_var = tf.get_variable("W") 
size_1 = tf.gather(temp_var, idx)
```

This approach gave me this mistake:
"Shape of a new variable (W) must be fully defined, but instead was unknown."

(again, I avoid hardcode and cannot write the shape like [number, number])

I changed the variables' scope, having thought it has smth to do with the scope, adding the lines:

```
with tf.variable_scope("my"):
```

and

```
with tf.variable_scope("my"):
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

But got this mistake:
"ValueError: Variable my/W does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?"
After setting reuse=None, I still have the same problem.

Would you be so kind and advice me how to fetch the value by index in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variable with get_variable for the first access too. For the later ones you need to set reuse=True.
Something like following should work:

```
W = tf.get_variable("W", initializer=tf.zeros([784, 10], dtype=YOUR_DTYPE)
...
temp_var = tf.get_variable("W", reuse=True)
tf.gather(...)
```

Comment: Thank you.
One cannot simply add reuse=True into variable:)
I added it to the scope, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/8c24XatB
But now I get the mistake ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
 From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'ones/shape' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [1,10], [10].

I know it's because of my efforts with idx, but I haven't even a slightest how to change the operation of getting number 784 by index without ruining the code to match the input shapes.